# jQuery AJAX set data multiple or single data to each field

Tags: json, ajax

I have AJAX/JSON operation that calls a PHP endpoint.

I'm getting data from database and need to set it to each field.

Here is the Ajax code:

```
$.ajax(
{
    url: "loadEquipmentDetails",
    type: "POST",
    data:
    {
        equipmentID: equipmentIDValue
    },
    success: function(jsonStr)
    {
        var data = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
        var item1Len = data.item1Name.length;

        $('#equipmentIDFilter').val(data.equipmentID);
        $('#equipmentNameFilter').val(data.equipmentName);

        for(var i=0; i<item1Len; i++)
        {
            var item1Name = data[i].item1Name;
            alert(item1Name);

            var newOption = $('<option>baba</option>');
            $('#item1IDFilter').append(newOption);
        }
    }
});
```

As you can see on above code, for this:

```
$('#equipmentIDFilter').val(data.equipmentID);
$('#equipmentNameFilter').val(data.equipmentName);
```

Working good, the value can be set to that ID.

But why the value is not show on below:

```
var newOption = $('<option>baba</option>');
$('#item1IDFilter').append(newOption);
```

I try to alert it alert(item1Name) but there is no result/pop up.

Response result:

[image]

Comment: You may use console.log(data) after the "parse", as it will show you all the data sent by php. Maybe there's an error on the php side...

Comment: Hi @Armage I just updated my question with screenshot result of it. I have checked into my PHP file and there is no error.

Comment: Maybe with `var item1Name = data.item1Name[i]`

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with the logic of your loop.

```
var item1Len = data.item1Name.length;
```

later on you have

```
    for(var i=0; i<item1Len; i++)
    {
        var item1Name = data[i].item1Name;
        alert(item1Name);

        var newOption = $('<option>baba</option>');
        $('#item1IDFilter').append(newOption);
    }
```

which assumes that `data` is an array, and each item has a key `item1Name`

I could only make assumptions of how your data looks like but I imagine it would have to be something like

```
for(var i=0, iMax = data.options.length; i<iMax; i++)
{
    if(data.options[i].hasOwnProperty('item1Name')) {
        var item1Name = data.options[i].item1Name;
        var newOption = $('<option>${item1Name}</option>');
        $('#item1IDFilter').append(newOption);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**: after the json was added to the question

```
if (data.hasOwnProperty('item1Name')) {
    for (var i = 0, iMax = data.item1Name.length; i < iMax; i++) {
        var item1Name = data.item1Name[i];
        var newOption = $('<option>${item1Name}</option>');
        $('#item1IDFilter').append(newOption);
    }
}
```